# How to check if a condition lasted for more than 15 mins?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Below is an example of the dataset

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 01:35 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 01:41 | 49 |
| 2020-01-01 01:46 | 50 |

I wish to check if the 'Value' was equal to 50 for continuous period of 15 mins. If yes, I want to extract the date for which it occurred.
Let me give an example what I mean by continuous period of 15 mins. Assume that I want to check if the value is equal to 50 for a continuous period of 5 mins (instead of 15 mins). The data that would satisfy this condition would be as follows

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 01:35 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 01:36 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 01:37 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 01:38 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 01:39 | 50 |

Then I want to extract the date`2020-01-01` onto a list because the above data was equal to 50 for a continuous period of 5 mins (or more).

Comment: You write about wanting to check intervals of 15 and 5 minutes but your data spans 15 and 5 seconds. Could you clarify which you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I about the typo. I changed the dataset into minutes. I am looking to check for intervals of 15 mins.

Comment: Would you mind a dummy variable being introduced?

Comment: @cegarza Sure! I dont mind that. I thought of doing that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting code for 5 mins so that output matches your desired output. Change `300` to `900` for 15 mins.
Steps:

1. Convert the `df['Date']` to `datetime` so that we can subtract two dates
   to know the time difference between them.
2. Group the `df` by date and Call `f` for each group object.
3. In `f`: `max-continuous_range` gives the
   length of longest segment where value is 50. `f` return True if length is 5 mins or more. Append date in list if `f` returns `True`.

Use:

```
def f(g):
   mask = (g['Value'] == 50)
   max_continuous_range = (np.max(np.cumsum(g['Date'].where(mask).diff()))
                         + timedelta(minutes = 1))
   return  max_continuous_range.seconds >= 300

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
groups = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.date, as_index = False)
final_list = [str(idx) for idx, g in groups if f(g)]
```

Input:

```
    Date  Value
0  2020-01-01 01:35     40
1  2020-01-01 01:36     50
2  2020-01-01 01:37     50
3  2020-01-01 01:38     50
4  2020-01-01 01:39     50
5  2020-01-01 01:40     50
6  2020-01-01 01:41     40
7  2020-01-01 01:42     40
```

Output:

```
>>> final_list
['2020-01-01']
```

**Inside f(g)**:

`mask`: True where value is 50.

```
    0    False
    1     True
    2     True
    3     True
    4     True
    5     True
    6    False
    7    False
```

`df['Date'].where(mask)` Puts NaT where mask is not True.

```
0                   NaT
1   2020-01-01 01:36:00
2   2020-01-01 01:37:00
3   2020-01-01 01:38:00
4   2020-01-01 01:39:00
5   2020-01-01 01:40:00
6                   NaT
7                   NaT
```

`.diff` gives difference between two consecuting elements. It will give NaT if any value is NaT. Result after `df['Date'].where(mask).diff()`:

```
0               NaT
1               NaT
2   0 days 00:01:00
3   0 days 00:01:00
4   0 days 00:01:00
5   0 days 00:01:00
6               NaT
7               NaT
```

Now cumulative sum of difference between consecutive times will give us the total time elapsed. After `np.cumsum(...)`:

```
0               NaT
1               NaT
2   0 days 00:01:00
3   0 days 00:02:00
4   0 days 00:03:00
5   0 days 00:04:00
6               NaT
7               NaT
```

`np.max` gives us the longest length. `1` minute is added to take care of boundary condition

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the code if possible?

Comment: @Sumit Does it work on your dataset? If yes, I will add the explanation.

Comment: yes it does. But I want to understand the code in order to know if the output is as desired.

Comment: @Sumit I have added the explanation. Do you want me to explain the logic in computation of `max_continuous_range`?

Comment: Yeah that would be great! Also, what is g here?

Comment: `g` is group object. Or simply the slice of data for a particular date. After `.groupby` on date, we have one g object for each date and we can access them by iterating `groups`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230871/discussion-between-amit-vikram-singh-and-sumit).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy variable that will essentially act as an id of continuous runs. The logic behind it is comparing each value with the next one in the series to see if the results are not equal. Then, we cast them to integers and make a cumulative sum. This means that the dummy variable will only increase when a streak ends. We can then groupby on this dummy variable, apply count, and filter based on your condition

```
df['dummy_id'] = (df['Value'] != df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()
grouped_df = df.groupby("dummy_id").agg({"dummy_id": "count", "date": "min"})
```

All you have to do then is filter according to what you were looking for and you should be good to go.