# Is the logic of the given code correct? The code is designed to do a cumulative sum whenever a given condition is True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want help in verifying if the logic of the given code is correct. My aim is to calculate the number of continuous seconds for which  `Value` is `>= 50.05`. So by continuous seconds I mean the `1s: 50.06 , 2s: 50.07, 3s:50.06`. Here the `Value` is above `50.05` for 3 seconds. What is not considered as continuous seconds is `1s: 50.06 , 2s: 50.02, 3s:50.06`. Here the condition for `2s` is not satisfied. I wrote down a code based on the what I read on the different questions on stack overflow.

The input data frame `df1` is as follows:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-12-31 23:00:00 | 50.10 |
| 2019-12-31 23:00:01 | 50.06 |
| 2019-12-31 23:00:02 | 50.05 |

The code used is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from datetime import timedelta
import example
accumulator = 0.0
reset = False

def myfunc(mask):
    global accumulator
    if mask==False:
        accumulator = 0.0
        return 0
    if mask==True:
        accumulator+=1.0
        return accumulator

df1 = example.get_pq() # to get dataframe

df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1[['Date','index']]=df1['index'].astype(str).str.split('+',expand=True)
del df1['index']
df1 = df1[['Date','Value']] 
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
groups = df1.groupby(df1['Date'].dt.date, as_index = False)
g = df1
g['mask 50.05'] = g['Value'] >= 50.05
g['Diff']= g['Date'].diff()
g['Diff'] =  g['Diff'].dt.total_seconds()
g['Sum 50.05']  = g.apply(lambda row: myfunc(row['mask 50.05']),axis=1)
print(g)
```

The output dataframe `g` is this:

| Date | Value | mask 50.05 | Diff | Sum 50.05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-12-31 23:00:00 | 50.10 | True | NaN | 0.0 |
| 2019-12-31 23:00:01 | 50.06 | True | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 2019-12-31 23:00:02 | 50.05 | True | 1.0 | 2.0 |

My aim is to extract the rows where the condition was satisfied for 900 seconds or more using `g[g['Sum 50.05'] >=900]`

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992900/how-to-check-if-a-condition-lasted-for-more-than-15-mins) a while ago, but the answer given there results in a different output than the code I posted here. Therefore, I needed help in verifying if the code I wrote here is correct. I have ran through a verification myself but wanted to make sure to have another pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

This is more pure Python solution
There should be more Pandas-way to do this.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2019-12-31 23:00:00','2019-12-31 23:00:01','2019-12-31 23:00:02','2019-12-31 23:00:03','2019-12-31 23:00:04'],
                 'Value':[50.1,50.06,50.05,49,52]})
dateVal=[]
def Above5005(row):
    if row['Value']<50.05:
        dateVal.append([row['Date'],0])
    elif dateVal and dateVal[-1][1]>0:
        dateVal[-1][1]+=1
    else:
        dateVal.append([row['Date'],1])
    print(dateVal) #this line shows how the statistics is collected by reference table dateVal
    return dateVal[-1][0]
df['refDate']=df.apply(Above5005,axis=1)
d=dict(dateVal)
#the below line link the data in reference table to main table
df['continuousCount']=df.apply(lambda row:d[row['refDate']],axis=1)
df
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain the code if possible?

Comment: Your code gives the same result as mine. But I am keen to understand the logic behind your code

Comment: @sumit I added a print() to show how the reference table (ref-key is the first date of the series of dates of >=50.05 values, ref-val is the count of continuous rows) is built. I think your code extracts the rows after there are already (e..g) 899 preceding rows of 50.05 or greater values, while my code extracts the preceding rows as well. So there is slight difference. Is my version closer to what you need?

Comment: Yes it does. Most importantly it helped me verify the logic of the code. The max value for `continuousCount` is equal the `Sum 50.05` in my code.